# Android Flutter Analyze Audio Waveform

Tags: android, audio, flutter

I want to create a music app that has a view that resembles the one of SoundCloud, this one to be clear: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZd39.png)

I thought of creating a class like this for each bar:

```
class Bar {
  const Bar(this.alreadyPlayed, this.index, this.height);

  final bool alreadyPlayed;
  final int index;
  final double height;
}
```

where alreadyPlayed is a bool that tells if the bar should be colored or Greyed out, index is the number of the bar and height, well is the height of the bar. The first two Variables shouldn't be difficult to obtain, my problem is to obtain the height of the bar, so the intensity of the music at that time. This is already enough, but even better if someone knows how to calculate the intensity of a specific frequency, for example, 225 Hz, that could be useful.

But anyway, if it helps, I am adding what I'm trying to achieve in pseudocode:

```
// Obtain the mp3 file.
//
// Define a number of bars decided from the song length 
// or from a default, for example, 80.
//
// In a loop that goes from 0 to the number of bars create 
// a Bar Object with the default alreadyPlayed as 0, index 
// as the index and the height as a 0.
// 
// Obtain the intensity of the sound in a way like this: 
// sound[time_in_milliseconds = song_lenght_in_milliseconds / num_of_bars ],
// and then set the height of the bar as the just found intensity.
```

Is what I'm asking possible?

Comment: Do you have experience decoding MP3 files? Or have a library in mind for this? I don't know of any dart libraries that do that directly, which means that you'll have to do it in native code and connect it to to flutter with platform channels unless you have one in mind....

Comment: I found audioplayer plugin (https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/audioplayer) which was used in this application: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FE7Vtzq52xg for a similar scope. But I don't know if this could be done using the same library. I don't really know how to decode an mp3. And what do you mean with native code and connect to flutter using platform channels?

Comment: Hi. Did you found a solution to get the waveform?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're looking into generating waveform graphs from audio. Have you tried anything so far?

There's no short answer here though. You can start exploring with [flutter_ffmpeg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg) to [generate waveform data from audio](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Waveform). It's up to you on what format you'll use for your waveform data. Once you got your data, you can generate waveform graphs in Flutter using [CustomPaint](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html). You can check the sample on this [blog post](https://matt.aimonetti.net/posts/2019-07-drawing-waveforms-in-flutter/). The waveform data used in the sample is in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for a way to listen microphone and make some audio analysis with flutter and I found some here that's may help you:

Is a two articles sequence that's explain step-by-step to draw Waveforms with Flutter

Generating Waveform Data - Audio Representation:
https://matt.aimonetti.net/posts/2019-06-generating-waveform-data-audio-representation/

Drawing Waveforms in Flutter: https://matt.aimonetti.net/posts/2019-07-drawing-waveforms-in-flutter/

I hope this help you

Comment: did implement listen microphone and draw waves functionality ?