# Use Java or other languages in a Flutter Application

Tags: java, android, audio, video, flutter

Since I got no answer and not much feedback on this question: [Android Flutter Analyze Audio Waveform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51894140/android-flutter-analyze-audio-waveform)
and found nothing online about what I'm looking for, I'll simply ask a broader question, since a comment on that answer told me to use native code and use a platform channel to connect it to flutter but when I asked some clarifications I got nothing.

So my question is If I can do operations in Java **(which has been around since a much longer time, and thus has a way bigger documentation)**, and then use the outcome in Flutter.

More precisely, could I do these things in Java and Flutter:

1) Analyse Audio waveform and find peak points in specific frequencies, and use the timestamp to display them in flutter;

Edit 1:
**What Are Peak Points?**

[image]

This Is the waveform of different frequencies ranges (The Orange one is bass (80-255Hz)), and the Points circled in black are Peak Points. I should analyze the audio specter of a song and Find the peak points in certain frequencies. Then When I Find the Peaks I need to save the timestamps, for example, 16 seconds in and so on.

2) Edit 2:
I need to Edit some photos in a video, like a video collage, for which each frame of a 30 or 60fps video is an image.

3) Edit 3: 
I need to add basic frame specific effects to the video, for example a blur that will change frame to frame, or a glare.

4) Adding Music to that video and save it to an mp4 or avi or any format.

5) Edit 4: Most Important thing, I don't want to this all in real time, but more like an After Effect like Render process, in which all the frames are rendered together. The Only thing that would be nice is a sort of progress bar telling the user that the Render is at frame, for example, 200 of 300, but I don't want to display any of the frames or the video, just to render it in background and then save it to an mp4 video that can be viewed after.

As You can see it's a difficult process to do in a language to which you hardly find a tutorial on how to play music due to its early state. But Uis and some other things in flutter are way easier to do and Flutter is also Multi-Platform. So I prefer to stick to Flutter language.

Edit 5:
I took a look at Qt and JUCE, and found out that Qt seems a valid alternative but it seems for what understood more like a "closed" system, I mean, for example I looked the multimedia library but for what I've understood, you can do basic stuff, for example play a video, but not collage frames and save it. (Don't know if I explained myself well). JUCE On the other side, looks better but it seems more for PC audio VST than for mobile applications including video rendering. And another thing is that these two are not free and open source like Flutter is.

Then There is Kivy, which could and could not be the best, because it is a Python port for Mobile Devices and I have a lot of experience with Python And I think it's one of the easier language to learn, but on the other side, it hasn't got that much UI power. and as you mentioned there could be problem using libraries on Android.

You stated I could use C++ or Java With Flutter, but with C++ you told that it's a difficult process. **So My question turned out to be Could I write the process in java with a Normal Android Application And Then in some way use the functions in a Flutter App?**

Edit 6:
**I found a possivle alternative:** 
Kha (http://kha.tech/). But again found nothing on how to use it with Flutter. **Could it be a good Idea?**

I'm asking more of a confirmation on if I could use Java or any other language to do what I need in a Flutter Application. And If yes if it's complicated or not that much. (I'm a beginner sorta). But Some tutorial or links to kickstart the code would be helpful aswell!

Comment: You can but that wouldn't be multi-platform. It'd be more a native plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flutter at this time is great for building UIs but as you've mentioned, it doesn't have a lot of power or compatibility with libraries yet. A good part of the reason for that is that it doesn't have easy integration with c++, but I won't get into [that](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/7053) now.

What you're asking is most likely possible but it's not going to be simple at all to do. First, it sounds like you're wanting to pull particular frames from a video, and display them - that's going to be an additional complication. And don't forget that on a mobile device you have somewhat limited processing power - things will have to be very asynchronous which can actually cause problems for flutter unless you're careful.

As to your points:

1. This is a very general ask. I'd advise looking up android audio processing libraries. I'm almost sure it's possible, but SO questions are not meant for asking advise on which framework to use. Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.
2. Once again, fairly general and a bit unclear about what you're asking... Try sofwarerecs. I assume you're wanting to take several frames and make them into a video?
3. Some of those effects (i.e. zoom) you could definitely do with flutter using a Transform. But that would just be while playing in flutter rather then adding to the video files themselves. To do that, you'll have to use the video library in android/java code.
4. Once again, the video library should do this.
5. This should also be part of the video library.

I do know of one audio/video library off the top of my head called [Processing](https://processing.org/) that *may* do what you need, but not for sure. It does have an android sdk though. [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) would be another but only for video/image processing and I haven't used it directly with Java so I'm not sure how easy it is to use.

For how you'd actually go about implementing this along with flutter... you're going to need to use [Platform Channels](https://flutter.io/platform-channels/). I mentioned them in the comment to your other answer but figured you could look that up yourself. The documentation does do a much better job of explaining how that works and how to set it up than I can. But the TLDR is that essentially, what they allow you to do is to send serialized data from native code (java/kotlin/swift etc) to flutter code (dart) and vice-versa, which gets translated into similar data structures in the target language. You can set up various 'channels' upon which the data flows, and within those channels set up 'methods' which get called at either end, or simply send events back and forth.

The complication I mentioned at the beginning is that sending images back and forth across the channels between flutter and dart isn't all that optimal. You most likely won't get a smooth 24/30/60fps of images being sent from java to dart, and it might slow down the rest of the flutter ui significantly. So what you'll want to use for the actual viewport is instead a [Texture](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Texture-class.html), which simply displays data from the android side. You'll have to figure out how to write to a texture from android yourself, but there's lots of information available for that. Controls, the visualization of the audio, etc can be done directly in flutter with data that is retrieved from native.

What you'll have is essentially a remote control written in dart/flutter, which sends various commands to a audio/video processing library & wrapper code in Java.

If all that sounds complicated, that's because it is. And as much as flutter is very nice to build UIs in, I have doubts as to whether it's going to be worth the extra complications if you're only targeting android.

---

*Not really related to the answer but rather some friendly advice:*

There is one other thing I'll mention - I don't know your level of proficiency with programming and with different languages, but video/audio processing and such are generally not done in java but rather in actual native code (i.e. c/c++). As such, there are actually two levels of abstraction you're going to have to be dealing with here (to some degree as it will probably be abstracted somewhat or a lot depending on the library you're using) - c/c++ to java and java to dart.

You may want to cut out the middlemen and work more directly with native - in that case I'd recommend at least taking a look at [Qt](https://www.qt.io/) or [JUCE](https://juce.com/) as they may be more suitable than flutter for your particular use case. There's also [Kivy](https://kivy.org/#home) (uses python) which may work well as there's a ton of image/video/audio processing libraries for Python somehow... although they may not all work on android and still have the c++ => python translation to some degree. You'll have to look into licensing etc though - Qt has a broad enough OS licence for most android apps, but JUCE you'd have to pay for unless you're doing open source. I'd have to recommend Qt slightly more than the others as it actually has native decoding of video frames etc, although you'd probably want to incorporate OpenCV or something for the more complicated effects you are talking about. But it would probably be on the same level of complicated as simply writing in java code, but with a slightly different UI style & easier integration with c++ libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer! But there are some points I didn't explain well, thus I edited the answer to make them clearer

Comment: There's a lot of points to your question, most of which aren't really a good fit for Stack Overflow which is really more about solving a particular coding issue. As to what I think your main question is though _(Could I write the process in java with a Normal Android Application And Then in some way use the functions in a Flutter App?)_ I did answer that - use Platform Channels as they enable communication between Java and Dart code.

Comment: Anyone know if this is still the case for Python >> Flutter?

Comment: python is definitely not natively supported in flutter. There has been some work on the dart FFI implementation which would allow integration with c/c++ libraries, which could theoretically be used for communication with python, but that's likely not going to happen for a while. You could theoretically integrate python however you'd normally do that in an android or ios app, and then go flutter -> java/kotlin -> python or flutter -> swift/obj-c -> python, but that's going to be difficult. If you really need to use python in a mobile app, take a look at [kivy](https://kivy.org)